# Angular 4 Unit Testing the code using window

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, window, karma-jasmine

I would like to test a code

```
public openAttachment(attachment: Attachment) {
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(attachment.getFile());
    }
    else {
        let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(attachment.getFile());
        window.open(objectUrl);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to get access to window or mock window in order to test it. I'm new to angular testing so it would be great if you could explain me in a detail please!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have access to the `window` object in your tests as well. So you can easily spy on them.

I've created a lightweight component with your particular usecase in mind.

Following is the component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-attachment',
  templateUrl: './attachment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./attachment.component.css']
})
export class AttachmentComponent {

  public openAttachment(attachment) {
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(attachment.getFile());
    }
    else {
      let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(attachment.getFile());
      window.open(objectUrl);
    }
  }

}
```

Note that here I'm not sure what the `Attachment` type is. So I've removed that type annotation from the parameters to the `openAttachment` function.

And now this is how my tests should look:

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AttachmentComponent } from './attachment.component';

describe('AttachmentComponent', () => {
  let component: AttachmentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AttachmentComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AttachmentComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AttachmentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('openAttachment', () => {
    let attachment;
    beforeEach(() => {
      attachment = { getFile: function() { return 'foo'; } };
    });

    it('should call `window.open` if `msSaveOrOpenBlob` is not a method present on the `window.navigator`', () => {

      // Since this will probably run on Chrome, Chrome Headless or PhantomJS, if won't have a `msSaveOrOpenBlob` method on it.
      // So this is the test for the else condition.
      let windowOpenSpy = spyOn(window, 'open');
      let returnValue = { foo: 'bar' };
      let urlCreateObjectSpy = spyOn(URL, 'createObjectURL').and.returnValue(returnValue);

      component.openAttachment(attachment);

      expect(urlCreateObjectSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');
      expect(windowOpenSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(returnValue);

    });

    it('should call the `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` if `msSaveOrOpenBlob` is present on the navigator object', () => {

      // To cover the if condition, we'll have to attach a `msSaveOrOpenBlob` method on the window.navigator object.
      // We can then spy on it and check whether that spy was called or not.
      // Our implementation will have to return a boolean because that's what is the return type of `msSaveOrOpenBlob`.
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob = function() { return true; };
      let msSaveOrOpenBlobSpy = spyOn(window.navigator, 'msSaveOrOpenBlob');

      component.openAttachment(attachment);

      expect(msSaveOrOpenBlobSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');

    });

  });

});
```

Again I'd like to emphasize on the fact that I'm not sure what the attachment type is going to be. So in the `beforeEach` block of my `openAttachment` describe block, I'm assigning it to an object that contains a key named `getFile` with value as a function that would eventually return a string `foo`.

Also since your tests would be running in Chrome by default, you won't get the `msSaveOrOpenBlob` function on the `window.navigator` object. So the first test in the `openAttachment` describe block would only cover the else block.

In the second test though, we've added `msSaveOrOpenBlob` as a function on the `window.navigator` object. So now it would be able to cover the `if` branch. So then you can create a spy on the `msSaveOrOpenBlob` function and `expect` this spy `toHaveBeenCalledWith` whatever is returned from the `attachment.getFile()` method(string `foo` in this case)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
beforeEach(() => {
```

//use the below line

```
 (<any>window).navigator ={ function msSaveOrOpenBlob() {} };

   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Your_Component);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;

   fixture.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Honestly this is good enough for me. We have a lot of custom properties on the window object and a lot of other answers I've found on SSO include a lot of extra work, including changing the code that we are testing which I didn't like. Thanks